# Automorphism group of a topological space

Tags: general-topology, group-theory

Let $G$ be any group. Is there a topological space $(X,\tau)$ such that the automorphism group $\textrm{Aut}(X,\tau)$ is isomorphic to $G$?

Comment: At least for finite groups it is true.

Comment: According to the thread http://mathoverflow.net/questions/37356/realizing-groups-as-automorphism-groups-of-graphs on MathOverflow, the answer is yes.

Comment: @JeremyRickard I don't understand; the topological automorphisms of a graph is a big group, much bigger than the group of graph theoretic automorphisms.

Comment: @MikeMiller The thread I pointed to contains a reference to a construction for topological spaces as well as one for graphs: de Groot, J. (1959), Groups represented by homeomorphism groups, Mathematische Annalen 138

Comment: @JeremyRickard Ah, thanks. Sorry, don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this has been answered by Tony Huynh on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37356/realizing-groups-as-automorphism-groups-of-graphs). In

> de Groot, J. ($1959$), *Groups represented by homeomorphism groups*, Mathematische Annalen $138$

the author shows that:

> "for *every* group $G$ one can find a complete, connected, locally connected *metric* space $M$ of any *positive* dimension such that $G \cong A(M)$"

where $A(M)$ denotes the autohomeomorphism group of $M$.